How to fix wobbling railing
I have a wood railing that is wobbly. It sits on top of a roof that has a waterproof membrane.
The posts are attached to the roof via a threaded rod and nut which is affixed to the roof. The nuts are hidden within the post at about 1 foot. The rod diameter is around 1 inch wide.
Any suggestions are appreciated.



I cannot enlarge the pictures to see details that may be important, like the condition of the bottoms of the post. If there is a nut that you know of and it is accessible, or can be made accessible, tighten the nut a bit more to compress the post to the roof. That is typically how this type of fastening works, if the post bottoms haven't started to decay.

The post bottoms are in good condition with no signs of rot.
Here is a closeup picture which hopefully is better.


Yes it is, if you can tighten the nut that is in the post, it should make it less wobbly. It still will to a degree, but should be noticeably better...... unless the main bolt lost its hold that goes into the roof/curb.

Thank you.
It looks like I can pop out the plug that is in the post.
What’s a good way to re-install the plug? Wood glue then some exterior grade filler?

If you drive a screw into the center of the plug and let the tip of the screw hit the nut inside it will act like a cork screw and possibly pop the plug, then again, maybe not. It may take a large gauge screw to do so. If it does, it can be glued back in, even if it comes out in 2 pieces to serve as a backer for the filler to flush up the repair. Glue the wood plug, not the filler. Filler has its own adhesive properties, if the surfaces are clean and sound.
